# Using yelp API c#

Tags: c#, api, oauth, yelp

I was wondering about how to use the Yelp API with an UWP C# app. I'm new to those things.

As I can understand from [here](https://www.yelp.co.uk/developers/documentation/v2/authentication) I need to authentificate using oauth, before I can do a `HttpClient` with a custom URI as shown [here](https://www.yelp.co.uk/developers/documentation/v2/search_api). How should I achieve this with code?

My guess was to do an `HttpClient` with a URI like this:

```
https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=San+Francisco&oauth_consumer_key=KEY&oauth_token=TOKEN&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=TOKEN_SECRET&oauth_timestamp=1470227235&oauth_nonce=cfd
```

Composed as

```
https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?
term=food
location=San+Francisco
oauth_consumer_key=KEY
oauth_token=TOKEN
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
oauth_signature=TOKEN_SECRET
oauth_timestamp=1470227235
oauth_nonce=cfd
```

Gives me the following output error :

> {"error": {"text": "Signature was invalid", "id": "INVALID_SIGNATURE", "description": "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: GET\u0026https%3A%2F%2Fapi.yelp.com%2Fv2%2Fsearch\u0026location%3DSan%2520Francisco%26oauth_consumer_key%HIDDEN%26oauth_nonce%3Dc%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1470227235%26oauth_token%HIDDEN%26term%3Dfood"}}

How should I get it to work? Is there any better method in c#

Comment: Have you tried passing the authentication data as a header in the request rather than in the request url?

Comment: Well, the fact is I don't know how to pass authentification data in the header